# packaging multiple javascript files

Tags: javascript, include

I am developing a javascript library made up of a few tightly coupled classes. The classes are broken up into individual .js files, but for brevity's sake, I envision the end user including a single .js file encompassing the entire implementation.

My question is, what is the ideal method for distributing the API? Should I simply repackage all the code into a single .js file, should I keep the existing file structure and setup a series of

```
document.write('<script src="file1.js"><\/script>');
```

commands into a 'primary' script file, or is there another way that makes more sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you don't intend for the user to jump in there and need to modify it and it's tightly coupled like you mentioned you should put it all in a single JS file and then [minify it](http://jscompress.com/).

You can provide an unminified version as well but seems for their simplicity you should put it all in a single JS file.

Comment: This is the way to go.  Writing out script includes to the DOM is messy and if the user doesn't make all the files available, your system breaks.  One minified file saves space and always works.  Short of a user editing it, it's always going to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For performance and maintenance reasons, I believe it's better to package them into a single file. The fewer http requests made to retrieve scripts, the better performance (in general - very long scripts can also cause performance slowdown.)  I'd also recommend namespacing your api.